# Proving that a "$1 - (1 - (\frac1m))^n$" Converges to $0.6321205588...$ when $m = n =$ large

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

- Suppose there a "$m$" objects
- One of these "$m$" objects is of interest (called "$m_0$")
- If you randomly select one of these "$m$" objects and then put it back, the probability of encountering "$m_0$" = $1 - \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^n$
- Naturally, Probability(finding "$m_0$" in "$n$" trials) = $1 - \left[\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)^n\right]$:

**My Question:** Supposedly, when $m = n =$ large number :

Probability(finding "$m_0$" in "$n$" trials) = $1 - \left[\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)^n\right] = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{e}\right) = 0.63.$

**Can someone please show me how to prove this?**

I tried verifying this for some individual examples:

- **Attempt 1** : $m = n = 100$

$1 - \left(\left(1 - \left(\dfrac{1}{100}\right)\right)^{100}\right) =  0.6339677$

- **Attempt 2** : $m = n = 1000$

$1 - \left(\left(1 - \left(\dfrac{1}{1000}\right)\right)^{1000}\right) =  0.6323046$

- **Attempt 3** : $m = n = 1000000$

$1 - \left(\left(1 - \left(\dfrac{1}{1000000}\right)\right)^{1000000}\right) =  0.6321207$

As we can see,  for $m = n$ = large : $1 - \left[\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)^n\right] = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{e}\right) = 0.63$ is *probably true* - **but can someone please show me how to mathematically show this?** Would this involve taking the limit of  $1 - \left[\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)^n\right]$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're saying $m=n$ so this is a single variable limit. $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=1-\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $m=n$, we can first remove one variable, to give us $1-(1-(\frac{1}{m}))^m$.

Taking the limit, we get $\lim_{m\to\infty}1-(1-(\frac{1}{m}))^m$.

As you may know, the definition of $e$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+(\frac{1}{m}))^m$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-(\frac{1}{m}))^m$ is $\frac{1}{e}$.

Thus, we get $1-\frac{1}{e}$, which converges to $0.6321205588\dots$